# Missing vendor asset in prod env of symfony error-handler

Tags: symfony, composer-php, production-environment, symfony5

After upgrading to symfony 5, I found a warning of a missing asset of symfony's error-handler:

> php.WARNING: Warning: include(/var/www/projekt/nakade/vendor/symfony/error-handler/ErrorRenderer/../Resources/assets/css/error.css): failed to open stream: No such file or directory {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0):

After investigating this issue I found the assets directory missing in prod environment while in dev env directory and css class is existing. 
I assume the css is missing because the component is just in require-dev.

`"require-dev": {
        ...
        "symfony/browser-kit": "5.0.*",
        "symfony/css-selector": "5.0.*",
        "symfony/debug-bundle": "5.0.*",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.13",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^5.0",
        "symfony/profiler-pack": "1.0.*",
        "symfony/test-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/var-dumper": "5.0.*"
    },`

The env var is set in .env.local  `APP_ENV=prod`
The error message showed up by the google-bot due to a missing robots.txt and sitemap.xml. THis is fixed and error and the warning is gone but I curious about it.

Has someone an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Can you share your .env from production (APP_ENV) ?

Comment: Ensure that APP_ENV is set to prod, you do not need error.css in production environment

Comment: .env.local on production  APP_ENV=prod |
.env APP_ENV=dev

as I know the .env is overwritten by .env.local - am I correct?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Like: dumping the environment? Can you share more details like a stacktrace that helps to locate where this error comes from?

Comment: good hint looking for the complete stacktrace... it was a deprecation in the twig.yaml which I fixed while upgrading to symfony5. It is gone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer by looking deeper at the stacktrace:

> [2020-04-16 23:33:35] php.CRITICAL: Uncaught Exception: The controller
>   for URI "/robots.txt" is not callable. Controller
>   "App\Controller\MyExceptionController" does neither exist as service
>   nor as class.. {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code:
>   ...

This is a hint to a deprecation in twig.yaml:

before:

> twig:
>       exception_controller: 'App\Controller\MyExceptionController'
>       ...

after:

> twig:
>       exception_controller: null
>       ...